# Why aren't comments included in indexing?

Tags: discussion

I agree that comments often are just chat, but at times they offer valuable additions to an answer. Yet they don't seem to be included in text search indexing. Why not?

Comment: personally I would rather them not be part of the search.

Comment: @Kellenjb: I guess we're going to have disagree. I recently searched for "PELCO", and I was disappointed to see "0 results", "Your search returned no matches.", even though I know there is at least one page that mention it (in comments) -- http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/65965/communication-between-ptz-camera-and-an-embedded-board .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a great part of the answer it should be edited into the answer. This site is not like a forum, sometimes comments can be productive, but they should not answer the question, it should be in the answer.

Comment: That's in agreement with the policy about [editing an answer](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/631/making-changes-to-someone-elses-answer), but there are very few people who actually do this. Most will post the extra information as a comment.

Comment: @Stevenvh, yes, that is one more thing that people have not completely started keeping speed with that is is very stackexchange and a major difference from forums. With time hopefully we can work our way to doing this. Help me remind people. There are always 300 things I have to try to help to remind people of.

Comment: @Kortuk: If you have to constantly remind people to do things, then that's a bug in the human factors aspect of the site.

Comment: @endolith - sometimes it's a sign that it's a Bad Idea tout-court.

Comment: @endolith, if it is something that is different from every other site and something I have never reminded people of but maybe 1 time on the site, it is just something we need to teach.(cc: @stevenvh)

Comment: @Kortuk - you can educate people to edit others' answers, or you could educate the answerer to pick up the comments and integrate them in his answer. I prefer the latter, maybe you already expected that ;-)

Comment: @Stevenvh, I also like it when the person whom answers edits their own question, but if you look at users above 2k or peer reviewed suggested edits by 10k users. If the original poster dislikes the edit, they can always edit it again. But it is free rep when you get an improved answer.

Comment: @steven there are already incentives to improve posts -- every edit bumps the question, and people will upvote an improved question or answer. Comments confer neither reputation points, nor bumps...